# Is there any way to make my newly created folders line up like they do in Windows?

Tags: finder, icon

When I create a new folder in the Finder, the folder icon's just floating there randomly where I clicked <kbd>Create Folder</kbd>. It's driving me mad. You know how in Windows when you create a new folder it aligns from the top left no matter where you click? Any way to make Mac do that?

Comment: See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/459545/119271) on a very similar question.

Comment: @Allan Using "clean up" was probably the only thing that I could find during my Google searching before I posted this. I was wondering if you could make the default behavior like that.

Comment: macOS takes the desktop metaphor much farther than Windows does.  Objects typically should stay where they are placed until they are moved.

Comment: How about just changing the view to *List view*?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a folder or desktop to sort by date added, which I think will do something similar [I'm not going to test it because I ***like*** where I already put everything & that the Mac doesn't automatically mess it all up like Windows does;)

[image]

Comment: I guess that can work too.